# Javascript: Can't reference window from parent

Tags: javascript

So i have a popup javascript calendar someone else wrote into my app.  What i am trying to do is reference it from the window that opens it, but the normal way of assigning the window.open to a variable is not working.  I think the issue is that the calendar, while being generated set itself as its opener.

```
    var vWinCal = window.open("", "Calendar", "width=200,height=250,status=no,resizable=yes,top=200,left=200,status=yes,menubar=yes");
vWinCal.opener = self;
vWinCal.focus();
var calc_doc = vWinCal.document;
calc_doc.write (str_buffer);
calc_doc.close();
```

It this my problem?  Is there a way around it?

Thanks

Comment: When you say it's "not working", what **exactly** do you mean?  Are there errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so i found my own problem.  the calendar AND the call to create it were in a seperate file that the parent window linked to.  My parent just never knew the variable cause of scope!  d'oh!  and to think of the time i wasted trying to fix this one!